# Source vs Static Network Address Translation

Tags: nat

Terminology in my research makes it unclear whether Source NAT(SNAT) and Static NAT(also SNAT) are the same concept. Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

They refer both to the same concept, that is **NAT** (Network Address Translation).
NAT aims at translating an IP to another one.

**Source NAT (SNAT)**

The NAT gateway automatically (ie. without interaction with an administrator) and uniquely map a local machine IP-port to a source global IP-port.

**Static NAT**

is not constraint to source NATing, but is mostly used for Destinatin NATing. In that case it is a simplified configuration optimized for the basic *port forwarding* ([source here](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeMAX/DNAT-vs-Port-Forwarding/td-p/922448))

In that case the port combination of destination (IP-port) is administratively bind to a local machine-port. This kind of configuration lack flexibility of "auto mapped" NAT.

Comment: Thank you. ;-) I see you are a fan of Ubiquiti...I just recently started looking at them.   To clarify:  SNAT & DNAT sound like two sides of the same coin like in a stateful connection, which also sounds like PAT used by most simple routers?...which again sounds like Masquerading.  The only unique feature differentiating any is Static NAT used if you have a static local global IP.  I do understand the concepts but the specifics of instances using each escape me. Can you break it down a bit for me please?

Comment: Yes in fact, there is many words for the same concept: (PAT=port forwarding= simplified static DNAT) and (Masquerading = Source NAT). However *Static NAT* does not deal with static global IP but static mapping local IP-port and global IP-port